# error in converting js code to jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, timer

I have a javascript/jquery code http://jsfiddle.net/9773D/ for timer.

I am trying to port it to jQuery Mobile code but I am confused about the pageinit,bind,live etc window events.

In the code i see that the error is because some elements in the tick() function are not loaded in DOM before it has been invoked in the code. Can someone help me in correcting my code.

Thanks,

Comment: you have code missing, where's your button_clicked() function?

Comment: `live('click',function(){...` is the button clicked code

Comment: @KevinB, I removed it and made the function as `$('.start').click .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your line to

`var timeDisplay = $(".time")[0];`

and that fixes it.

**Edit:**

*Adding explanation:*

Since you used innerHTML instead of `$('.time').html("")`, you needed to set timeDisplay to the HTML node, since `innerHTML` is a property of the node, not the jQuery object that is returned by the selector `$('.time')`.

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't explain why. Answers on SO should be useful to more ppl than just the OP.

Comment: Since you used `innerHTML` instead of `$('.time').html("")`, you needed to set `timeDisplay` to the HTML node, since `innerHTML` is a property of the node, not the jQuery object that is returned by the selector `$('.time').

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how it could be done in a more jquery'sh way. http://jsfiddle.net/9773D/1/

```
timedisplay.innerHtml = "" //does not work since timedisplay is a jquery object 
//timedisplay[0] is the html object so on that innerHtml does work
```

But jquery has the function `.html("");`

```
timedisplay.html(""); // is a bit cleaner
```